# Quisiera condicionar el combobox dependiente para que muestre ciertos datos de la base datos y no todos de la tabla selecionada

Tags: java, xampp

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDr5D.png)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido de preferencia que tu codigo sea texto no una imagen es mas facil para leerlo

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Por favor, copiar el codigo de la pregunta en la pregunta y no en imagenes. Ademas ser un poco mas descriptivo con el problema.

Comment: solamente tienes que poner un where con la condicion que decees en el query que utilizas para obtener los registros de la base

Comment: Puedes como ya dijeron usar un where en tu consulta o a la hora de llenar el combobox, pon tu código y tu consulta en vez de imágenes, es más fácil de leer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hola te pongo un ejemplo compañero, yo trato de la tabla de clientes obtener únicamente aquellos que estan como activos en mi BD y que son por ejmplo de la CDMX.

```
SELECT * FROM tb_clientes WHERE cliente_status = 1 AND residencia_cliente = 'CDMX';
```

Con lo anterior ya tu combobox no se llenará de toda la info. de tu tabla si no solo con aquello que es relevante para ti mostrar en la vista del usuario.

Saludos

Comment: gracias por la ayuda men, lo pondre en practica